# get data from server using ajax and put it in a datatable

Tags: python, ajax, django, json, datatable

i have an array of data, in which each element is a dictionary. like this:

```
list = [{'id': '1', 'name':'first', 'type': 'item', 'status': 'ok'},
        {'id': '2', 'name':'second', 'type': 'item', 'status': 'ok'},
        {'id': '3', 'name':'third', 'type': 'kit', 'status': 'ok'}]
```

i have a dataTable in my web page that for each row, there is an option to delete, 
when user deletes some row, there is an ajax call to the server to delete the item from the list too. but there is a problem in showing new data in the table. table doesn't recognize that it should be initialized again. for example i use

```
{{ forloop.counter }}
```

for showing line numbers and if i delete some row, number column doesn't refresh and there are still old numbers. so i can't use line numbers for deleting rows anymore, because they are not in the range.
i was wondering if i give new data to dataTable. but i don't know how to do it in response to an ajax call. 
also i'v been trying a lot to redraw dataTable but it didn't work.

BTW I use django and python and i don't wanna use asp or php code lines

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem
i don't get back data from server 
i just remove some row and the redraw the table using new nodes as aaData and aoColumns BTW
i actually set bDestroy to true for redrawing
for server side process, i use some hidden input and send the removed element's id
code lines are here 
this is ajax code:

```
var required_data = {deleted_nodes:tr_id};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url:$('#items_form').attr('action'),
    data:required_data,
    success:function () {
    }
});
```

this is the code for redrawing the table:

```
var table = $('#itemsTable').dataTable({"bRetrieve":true});
var nodes = table.fnGetNodes();
table.fnDeleteRow(nodes[parseInt(tr_number) - 1], null, true);
nodes = table.fnGetNodes();
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    data.push(
            {
                count:(i + 1).toString(),
                name:nodes[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
                type:nodes[i].cells[2].innerHTML,
                specialName:nodes[i].cells[3].innerHTML,
                status:nodes[i].cells[4].innerHTML,
                manage:nodes[i].cells[5].attributes['id']
            }
    );
}
var oSettings = {
    "aaData":data,
    "aoColumns":[
        {"sTitle":"number", "mDataProp":"count", "style":"width:10px;"},
        {"sTitle":"name", "mDataProp":"name", "style":"width:50px;"},
        {"sTitle":"type", "mDataProp":"type", "style":"width:50px;"},
        {"sTitle":"special name", "mDataProp":"specialName", "style":"width:50px;"},
        {"sTitle":"status", "mDataProp":"status", "style":"width:50px;"},
        {"sTitle":"management", "mDataProp":"manage", "style":"width:25px; text-align: center;"}
    ],
    "sScrollY":"500px",
    "bPaginate":false,
    "bScrollCollapse":true,
    "bFilter":false,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "fnRowCallback":function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        var str = '<span><img src="' + 'error.png' +
                '" name="delete"' + ' style="width:20px;height:20px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                'onclick="' + "delete_item('" + aData.count + "', '" + aData.manage.value + "');" +
                '" class="small-icon"' + ' title="delete this" /></span>' +
                '<span><img src="' + 'warning.png' +
                '" name="edit"' + ' style="width:20px;height:20px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                'onclick="' + "report_problem('" + aData.count + "', '" + aData.manage.value + "', '" + aData.type + "');" +
                '" class="small-icon"' + ' title="edit this" /></span>';
        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html(str);
        $('td:eq(5)', nRow)[0].setAttribute('id', aData.manage.value);
    }
};
table.dataTable('#itemsTable', oSettings);
```

i have used element's ID as the ID of fifth TD in each row
so i retrieve this by:

```
manage:nodes[i].cells[5].attributes['id']
```

after that i use fnRowCallback to actually do two tasks:
1- use some picture elements for creating a good user interface. it's accomplished by using

```
$('td:eq(5)', nRow).html(str);
```

2- set the ID for fifth TD again for further use. it's accomplished by using

```
$('td:eq(5)', nRow)[0].setAttribute('id', aData.manage.value);
```

;-)